# Apache camel stopping my downloading route instance

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

Am currently a beginner in using Apache Camel, am starting my download instance and then making thread sleep for a while and then stopping it like below is there a better way to handle this other than using Thread.sleep

```
    Main main = new Main();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new MyFtpServerRouteBuilder());
    main.enableHangupSupport();
   //Starting my main camel instance
    main.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000);
   //stopping my main camel instance
    main.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this FAQ

- http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone.html

And then this how to keep Camel running in standalone mode

- http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following. This will run your camel context until you kill or stop the process.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Main main = new Main();
    main.enableHangupSupport();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new MyFtpServerRouteBuilder());
    main.run(args);
}
```